# Neo4j Casual Clustering - Servers cannot discover each other

Tags: neo4j, raft

I was trying to deploy a Neo4j (3.1 enterprise) Causal cluster,
I've read the Operations Manual very carefully, and tried to create a 3 core cluster on my local machine (using both fresh installations and docker).
But, when I'm trying to deploy the cluster on different machines (Google Cloud Compute) all cluster members are stuck at:

```
Starting Neo4j.
2017-03-23 09:07:47.164+0000 INFO  No SSL certificate found, generating a self-signed certificate..
2017-03-23 09:07:47.886+0000 INFO  Starting...
2017-03-23 09:07:49.108+0000 INFO  Bolt enabled on 0.0.0.0:7687.
2017-03-23 09:07:49.126+0000 INFO  Initiating metrics...
2017-03-23 09:07:49.374+0000 INFO  My connection info: [
    Discovery:   listen=0.0.0.0:5000, advertised=<ip1>:5000,
    Transaction: listen=0.0.0.0:6000, advertised=<ip1>:6000,
    Raft:        listen=0.0.0.0:7000, advertised=<ip1>:7000,
    Client Connector Addresses: bolt://localhost:7687,http://localhost:7474,https://localhost:7473]

2017-03-23 09:07:49.377+0000 INFO  Discovering cluster with initial members: [<ip1>:5000, <ip2>:5000, <ip3>:5000]
2017-03-23 09:07:49.378+0000 INFO  Attempting to connect to the other cluster members before continuing...
```

I tried to use public/private IP's, changing the ports, I've also checked that the 5000 port is open (yes I've added the required firewall rules) using:

```
nc -zv <ip2> 5000
Connection to <ip2> 5000 port [tcp/*] succeeded!
```

But still no luck getting the cluster up, Anyone?

EDIT:

I'm running the following docker containers on different GCP machines:

```
docker run --name=neo4j-core --detach \
     --publish=7474:7474 --publish=7687:7687 \
     --publish=5000:5000 --publish=7000:7000 \
     --env=NEO4J_dbms_mode=CORE \
     --env=NEO4J_causalClustering_expectedCoreClusterSize=3 \
     --env=NEO4J_causalClustering_initialDiscoveryMembers=<core1-public-address>:5000,<core2-public-address>:5000,<core3-public-address>:5000 \
     --env=NEO4J_causalClustering_discoveryAdvertisedAddress=<public-address>:5000 \
     --env=NEO4J_causalClustering_transactionAdvertisedAddress=<public-address>:6000 \
     --env=NEO4J_causalClustering_raftAdvertisedAddress=<public-address>:7000 \
     neo4j:3.1-enterprise
```

Comment: Please supply your Neo config files